# How to generate random number including date?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How to make unique number combination using current date and time and concatenating with random number from a specific range

Comment: what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

for generating random value you can use this

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((maxrange - minrange) + 1) + minrange;
```

for get  current time and date 
You could use:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

combine the two ones for unique value

```
 String uniqueValue = randomNum+""+seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
String uniqueValue = randomNum+""+time;
```